# How to use Binding in self-defined UserControl in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I try to make a UserControl to encapsulate a part of xaml.

like below.

this is xaml for MyTextBox

```xml
<UserControl
  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MyTextBox}"
  d:DesignHeight="300"
  d:DesignWidth="300"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  x:Class="DependencyPropertyLearn.MyTextBox"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DependencyPropertyLearn"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Border Background="Coral">
    <TextBox
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      Text="{Binding MyText}"
      VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  </Border>
</UserControl>
```

this is C# for MyTextBox

```
public partial class MyTextBox : UserControl
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyText), typeof(string),
            typeof(MyTextBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnMyTextChanged) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });

    public string MyText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(MyTextProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnMyTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myTextBox = d as MyTextBox;
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

and when I use it in my MainWindow,

like below:

```xml
<Window
  Height="450"
  Title="MainWindow"
  Width="800"
  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModel}"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  x:Class="DependencyPropertyLearn.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DependencyPropertyLearn"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>
    <local:MyTextBox MyText="{Binding Name}" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

and ViewModel for MainWindow is:

```
public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty] private string _name;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _name = "silly";
    }
}
```

The result is below. It seems like not work for binding between ViewModel and MainWindow and UserControl.

[image]

I expect that I can change `name` in ViewModel and then change the `MyText` in `MyTextBox` , and I can see `MyText` on the screen. like

[image]

Comment: I would recommend creating a regular WPF property instead of relying on magic from a third party library to generate your property. Both to eliminate errors or incorrect usage of the library, and since it makes the question easier to read by anyone unfamiliar with the library.